# how to place elements in a line in a certain block inside the finished grid?

Tags: html, css

how to place elements in a line in a certain block inside the finished grid?

I tried through
justify-self: end;
align-self: end;

but they continue to go vertically down
I need to place the buttons horizontally in one line in one of the divs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.